# How may I return a value to an input field using JQuery Datepicker populated in a JavaScript pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have implemented a [JQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#show-week) as an inline calendar, ie. without the associated text field. This DatePicker should be automately shown in a pop up window when user clicks on a calendar .gif and return the value in format `YYYYMMDD` to an input field on the associated JSP page.

I've managed to generate the pop up after clicking the calendar image and also to implement the calendar in the pop up and generate the date value in the correct format. However, I'm not sure about how to return this value to the JSP page.

JSP page:

`<html:img src="/calendarimg/cal.gif" onclick="popUp('updIntroDate');"/>`

POP up window:

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=no,location=yes,resizable=no,scrollbar=no,status=yes,
 location=no,toolbar=no,height=200,width=200";

function popUp()    {
   windowObjetReference = window.open("datepickercalendar.html", "DatePicker",
       strWindowFeatures);
 }
```

The DatePicker function:

```
<script>
  $(function DatePicker(updIntroDate) {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
    onSelect: function(v)   {
        //var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        alert(v);
        },
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
});
});
</script>
<div id=datepicker></div>
</body>
```

The alert I've put in the Date-picker function shows the date in the correct format when clicking any date in the calendar. How may I send this value back, through the popup function back to my JSP page and populate the input field there?

Comment: Please add the code that has the input element you want to populate.

Comment: You are using a window.open function, why don't you use the jquery's popup function? It makes it easier to pass variable to and from a popup window

Comment: I don't want the pop up to be generated the original way the Datepicker widget is generated (clicking inside an input field and the DP is shown sliding down). I want to generate a pop up and have the DP shown inside that window.

Comment: This is the inpiut field I want to populate with the date send from the DP:
    <html:text style="width: 70%;" styleClass="fld" property="updIntroDate" maxlength="8" tabindex="8"
     ondblclick="now=new Date();if(this.value=='') this.value=now.getFullYear()+''+((now.getMonth()+1)<10?'0'+(now.getMonth()+1):(now.getMonth()+1))+''+(now.getDate()<10?'0'+now.getDate():now.getDate());"/>

Comment: According to the [JQuery API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) I should be able to do something like:
  $(function DatePicker() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
('getDate', 'dateFormat', 'yymmdd'),
     dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
        onSelect: function(dateObject) {
         var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate', 'dateFormat');
         alert(dateObject);
         },
        showWeek: true,
       firstDay: 1,
    });
  });
However this just returns the date as 'Thus Feb 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT...
@DmytroShevchenko

Comment: Are you getting the selected date in alert?

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how to return it to the pop up and then to the form (via the pop up).

Comment: Why don't you keep some hidden text box in your form and set this alert value in that?

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to return the actual value from the DatePicker function. I get the value correct in 'v' but how may I return this value and use it in my JSP page?